# Laptop web camera "active" history

Tags: webcam, history

Is there a way to see the history of when my web camera has been active? For example during the previous day?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question you must first understand the webcam is "always active" just like your keyboard or mouse. To see list of active devices:

```
$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Performance MX                   id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech K800                             id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint                  id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_HD               id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

What you need to look at are the applications that use the webcam such as `Skype` and see what usage log files (if any) they maintain. If they don't maintain log files you can create a wrapper script to maintain your own log files. It can get really complicated when webcams can be used by the Browser because that could mean downloading Chromium source code and modifying it.

A decade ago people laughed when I put masking tape over the webcam. Now days it is common practice for many. Especially when you learn of all the webcam spying software out there.

A couple years ago I took broken earbuds, cut the wires off to the male jack and plugged it into the microphone jack on the laptop. Now there is something new to laugh at ;)

Answer (score 0):

Technically, it is possible to do, but realistically, no.

You might find this possible duplicate of value:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/80285/do-webcams-generates-logs-on-operating-system