# How to know if the internal webcam is being used by someone else without our permission

Tags: permissions, webcam

I use Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS.

In my laptop, as it's usual, there is an internal webcam, and I've read about it is possible that someone (external evil hacker) could use it without my permission and without I see some "rare" behaviour in the machine (not warning light, etc).

Is there a way to know if the cam is being operated even if we aren't use it?

Maybe some command line? ???

Of course, this question could be extended to other hardware devices... (microphones, modems, bluetooth, HDD, etc etc etc)

Comment: If it worries you, then stick a piece of opaque tape over the camera. And blacklist the camera driver (and microphone). And make sure you don't leave open, insecure ports for evildoers to enter by. Proper security is a set of good maintenance habits, good online habits, and ongoing learning. There is no quick-fix.

Comment: See this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/848245/laptop-web-camera-active-history

Comment: OH! Now I see the only real security way to be absolutely safe about this, is... TO DISCONNECT the web cam and the mike!!! But... I think it would be very nice if Linux would have some kind of control over this. Just my humble opinion. Thanks a lot for your data guys!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see what processes are accessing a webcam using `lsof /dev/video1` or `fuser /dev/video1` - substitute the path with that of the device you wish to know about.

You can list webcam devices with `v4l2-ctl --list-devices`.